# JQuery - Trigger event when scrolling towards top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

My homepage starts with a header (position: absolute) and a full-width slider.

I want the header to appear (position: fixed) **when the user is scrolling towards the top of the page** and moving back to absolute again when the scroll reaches the slider.

I have looked into at least 15 different StackOverflow and other websites similar question but I can't find a solution. Can someone help please?

```js
function stickyHeader() {
  let scrollPoint = window.scrollY;
  let sliderHeight = jQuery('.swiper-home').outerHeight();
  jQuery(window).scroll(function (){
    if (scrollPoint > sliderHeight){
      if(//scrolling towards top){
        header.addClass("fixed-header");
      } else {
        header.removeClass("fixed-header");
      }
    }
  })
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', stickyHeader);
```

Comment: Following the solution after asking for support to my senior: